# How to get text from slide in C# using Aspose

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, aspose-slides

i am getting all shapes in slides of ppt file now i want to get text from those shapes how can i do this

here is my method where i am getting shapes of all slides in ppt file

```
public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // The path to the documents directory.
        string dataDir = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\Vipin\Desktop\");
        //Load the desired the presentation
        Presentation pres = new Presentation(dataDir + "Android.ppt");
        using (Presentation prestg = new Presentation(dataDir + "Android.ppt"))
        {


            //Accessing a slide using its slide index
            int slideCount = prestg.Slides.Count();
            for (int i = 0; i <= slideCount - 1; i++)
            {
                ISlide slide = pres.Slides[i];
                foreach (IShape shap in slide.Shapes)
                {
                    int slideCountNumber = i + 1;

                    float shapeHeight = shap.Frame.Height;
                    float shapeWidth = shap.Frame.Width;
                    Debug.Write("slide Number: " + slideCountNumber + " shape width = " + shapeWidth + " shapeHeight = " + shapeHeight);

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

now ho can i get the text from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aspose will give u truncated text if u don't have the license of it. so it will be better for you if you will use Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

use as below

```
public void ReadSlide(){

        string filePath= @"C:\Users\UserName\Slide.pptx";

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application PowerPoint_App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations multi_presentations = PowerPoint_App.Presentations;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation presentation = multi_presentations.Open(filePath, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

        string presentation_textforParent = "";
        foreach (var item in presentation.Slides[1].Shapes)
        {
            var shape = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape)item;
            if (shape.HasTextFrame == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
            {
                if (shape.TextFrame.HasText == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                {
                    var textRange = shape.TextFrame.TextRange;
                    var text = textRange.Text;

                    presentation_textforParent += text + " ";
                }
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: What is presentation_textforParent?  It looks like it's supposed to be the final return value, but why name it presentation_textforParent?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to extract text not from all shapes, but from text frames instead. In order to do this use the `GetAllTextFrames` static method exposed by the `PresentationScanner` class

```
using (Presentation prestg = new Presentation(dataDir + "Android.ppt"))
{
   //Get an Array of ITextFrame objects from all slides in the PPTX
   ITextFrame[] textFramesPPTX = Aspose.Slides.Util.SlideUtil.GetAllTextFrames(pptxPresentation, true);

   //Loop through the Array of TextFrames
   for (int i = 0; i < textFramesPPTX.Length; i++)

   //Loop through paragraphs in current ITextFrame
   foreach (IParagraph para in textFramesPPTX[i].Paragraphs)

       //Loop through portions in the current IParagraph
       foreach (IPortion port in para.Portions)
       {
           //Display text in the current portion
           Console.WriteLine(port.Text);

           //Display font height of the text
           Console.WriteLine(port.PortionFormat.FontHeight);

           //Display font name of the text
           if (port.PortionFormat.LatinFont != null)
               Console.WriteLine(port.PortionFormat.LatinFont.FontName);
       }
```

See [documentation](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesnet/Extracting+Text+from+the+Presentation)

Comment: it showslike 'Click... text has been truncated due to evaluation version limitation' @Max Brodin

Comment: @NeerajMehta It means that Aspose libriary is not free and you have to buy it before use.

Comment: is there any other method or library which is free to do this?

Comment: i have used another method for this by using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging; but getting error when opening a file  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026179/getting-corrupted-file-error-while-trying-to-open-microsoft-powerpoint-file-usin