# Getting corrupted file error while trying to open Microsoft Powerpoint file using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

i am getting corrupted file error when opening ppt file using C#

```
public void Slide()
    {
        string dataDir = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\Vipin\Desktop\");
        using (PresentationDocument doc = PresentationDocument.Open(dataDir + "Android.ppt", true))
        {
            // Insert other code here.
        }
    }
```

and the error is

[image]

Comment: Wait! You are opening the file on the server?

Comment: ahat are you saying sir?

Comment: He says that's a terribly wrong idea.

Comment: Your question is tagged with asp.net. Are you trying to open the presentation or just reading the file for some other purpose?

Comment: @DavidBrabant If that's really the case, I sure hope someone's told Google they shouldn't be doing server-side conversion of PowerPoint files.

Comment: @pixelbadger  He didn't say that he has a google data center at hand ...

Comment: Did you try with PresentationDocument.Open(dataDir + "Android.ppt", false) ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see on MSDN, PresentationDocument is coming from the OpenXML SDK, yes? If so, this only supports OpenXML documents using the PresentationML format.

The `.ppt` extension on your file (rather than `.pptx`) suggests it is the older binary format, which isn't supported. As a test, save a copy of the file as a `.pptx` and see if this works.

You've mentioned success using Aspose in a comment. Aspose Slides does support the older binary format, which would lend evidence to my theory.